# ¿Cómo enviar la cadena correctamente?

Tags: javascript

```
String.prototype.deleteA = function(a) {


  var $a = a.toString().replace(new RegExp('a', 'g'), '');


  return $a;

};

var c = "holaa!".deleteA(this);
```

*Estoy intentando hacer una funcion mediante el prototipo de `String`, busca las coincidencias de 'a' y retorna la cadena sin 'a', **pero tengo 2 problemas**..*

> 1 ) ¿Cómo puedo pasar la cadena en sí?, porque al pasar 'this' estoy
>   pasando el contexto de window, pero no sé como pasarlo.
>
> 2) Como también puedo reemplazar las 'A', sin hacer lowerCase a toda
>   la cadena

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacer referencia a la cadena utilizando la palabra clave `this` dentro de la función. No necesitas pasar ningún parámetro.

Para hacer la búsqueda de la expresión regular case insensitive (que no diferencia mayúsculas de minúsculas) utiliza el flag `i`

```js
String.prototype.deleteA = function() {
  return this.replace(new RegExp('a', 'gi'), '');
};

var c = "holaa! A B C a b c".deleteA();

console.log(c);
```

Comment: gracias gracias Asier!!